# Table row data align vertically

Tags: html, css, printing, html-table, datatables

In my project I have a contacts Table with some information column like below

```
<table>
   <thead>
       <tr>
         <th>Name</th>
         <th>Designation</th>
         <th>Organization</th>
         <th>Address</th>
       </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
       <tr>
         <td>Aziz</td>
         <td>Executive</td>
         <td>BIBT</td>
         <td>Dhaka</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Mizan</td>
         <td>Manager</td>
         <td>BIBT</td>
         <td>Dhaka</td>
       </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This form result like below

```
Name    Designation    Organization     Address
----   ------------   --------------   ----------
Aziz    Executive      BIBT             Dhaka
Mizan   Manager        BIBT             Dhaka
```

But in my case I need another view for this table for print, that will show the result like below,

```
  | Aziz            |  |     Mizan           |
  | Executive, BUBT |  |     Manager, BUBT   |
  | Dhaka           |  |     Dhaka           |
```

How can I achieve this layout for my table? one thing I am using datatable plugin, and I need this layout only for print purpose. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can transpose your table using javascript. I am assuming you are using jquery,

First, you need to alter your HTML markup a bit,
You can hide and show elements based on CSS media queries, so, I am adding relevant classes to the span and td.

```
  <table>
   <thead>
       <tr>
         <th>Name</th>
         <th>Designation</th>
         <th>Organization</th>
         <th>Address</th>
       </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
       <tr>
         <td>Aziz</td>
         <td>Executive<span class = 'display-on-print'> ,BIBT</span></td>
         <td class = 'hide-on-print'>BIBT</td>
         <td>Dhaka</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Mizan</td>
         <td>Manager <span display-on-print> ,BIBT</span></td>
         <td class = 'hide-on-print'>BIBT </td>
         <td>Dhaka</td>
       </tr>
    </tbody>
 </table>
 <button>Transpose</button>
```

Now, you can use jquery to transpose the table,

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $("table").each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var newrows = [];
        $this.find("tr").each(function(){
            var i = 0;
            $(this).find("td").each(function(){
                i++;
                if(newrows[i] === undefined) { newrows[i] = $("<tr></tr>"); }
                newrows[i].append($(this));
            });
        });
        $this.find("tr").remove();
        $.each(newrows, function(){
            $this.append(this);
        });
    });

    return false;
});
```

Comment: Can I export the new layout to another tab for print and preserve my main table intact?

Comment: You don't need that. The method I provided transposes the table, so if you call the function twice, it will again transpose the table in its original form, so your approach should be: transpose() --> window.print() --> transpose(). This will transpose the table, opens up the print tab and again transposes the table back to its original state

Answer (score -2):

```html
<table>
   <tbody>
<thead>
       <tr>
         <td>Aziz</td>
         <tr>
           <td>Executive <span> BIBT </span></td>
     </tr>
<tr>
  <td>Dhaka</td>
     </tr>
       </thead>
  </tbody>
</table>
```